# Multiple Dependencies JQuery Form

Tags: jquery, forms

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#c86").bind("change",function(){
  var selectedValue=$(this).val().toLowerCase();
  switch(selectedValue){
   case "bmattress": 
    $("#c92").show();   
    $("#c97").hide();
    $("#c103").hide();
    break;
   case "mattress": 
    $("#c92").hide();   
    $("#c97").show();
    $("#c103").hide();
    break;
   case "tmattress": 
    $("#c92").hide();   
    $("#c97").hide();
    $("#c103").show();
    break;
   case "-": 
    $("#c92").hide();   
    $("#c97").hide();
    $("#c103").hide();
    break;
   default:
    break;
  }
 });
});
```

```css
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<label class="control-label" for="c86">Main Choice</label>

<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon left"><i class="fa fa-product-hunt"></i> </span>
<select class="form-control" onChange="displayForm(this)" id="c86" name="c86" data-rule-required="true">
  <option  value="-">- Select -</option>
  <option  value="bmattress">Bed</option>
  <option  value="mattress">Mat</option>
  <option  value="tmattress">Top</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="c92" class="form-group c92 " data-cid="c92" style="display: none">
  <label class="control-label" for="c92">First dropdown</label>

<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon left"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> </span>
<select class="form-control" name="c92"  
    >
  <option  value="">- Select -</option>
  <option  value="1">1</option>
  <option  value="2">2</option>
  <option  value="3">3</option>
  <option  value="4">4</option>
  <option  value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
</div>
  
</div>




<div id="c97" class="form-group c97 "  style="display: none" data-cid="c97">
  <label class="control-label" for="c97">Second dropdown</label>

<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon left"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> </span>
<select class="form-control" name="c97"   
    >
  <option  value="">- Select -</option>
  <option  value="1">1</option>
  <option  value="2">2</option>
  <option  value="3">3</option>
  <option  value="4">4</option>
  <option  value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
</div>
  
</div>




<div id="c103" class="form-group c103"  style="display: none" data-cid="c103">
  <label class="control-label" for="c103">Third dropdown</label>

<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon left"><i class="fa fa-stop-circle"></i> </span>
<select class="form-control" name="c103"   
    >
  <option  value="">- Select -</option>
  <option  value="1">1</option>
  <option  value="2">2</option>
  <option  value="3">3</option>
  <option  value="4">4</option>
  <option  value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
</div>
  
</div>
```

I have a dropdown with jquery which appears/hides other dropdown according to choices. It works OK but i want to have a fourth dropdown which appears when we select something on third dropdown. It seems that when i have id on root div it doesn't work does anybody knows how to fix this?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#c86").bind("change",function(){
        var selectedValue=$(this).val().toLowerCase();
        switch(selectedValue){
            case "bmattress": 
                $("#c92").show();           
                $("#c97").hide();
                $("#c103").hide();
                break;
            case "mattress":    
                $("#c92").hide();           
                $("#c97").show();
                $("#c103").hide();
                break;
            case "tmattress":   
                $("#c92").hide();           
                $("#c97").hide();
                $("#c103").show();
                break;
            case "-":   
                $("#c92").hide();           
                $("#c97").hide();
                $("#c103").hide();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    });
});
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<label class="control-label" for="c86">Main Choice</label>

<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon left"><i class="fa fa-product-hunt"></i> </span>
<select class="form-control" onChange="displayForm(this)" id="c86" name="c86" data-rule-required="true">
  <option  value="-">- Select -</option>
  <option  value="bmattress">Bed</option>
  <option  value="mattress">Mat</option>
  <option  value="tmattress">Top</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="c92" class="form-group c92 " data-cid="c92" style="display: none">
  <label class="control-label" for="c92">First dropdown</label>

<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon left"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> </span>
<select class="form-control" name="c92"  
    >
  <option  value="">- Select -</option>
  <option  value="1">1</option>
  <option  value="2">2</option>
  <option  value="3">3</option>
  <option  value="4">4</option>
  <option  value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
</div>

</div>




<div id="c97" class="form-group c97 "  style="display: none" data-cid="c97">
  <label class="control-label" for="c97">Second dropdown</label>

<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon left"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> </span>
<select class="form-control" name="c97"   
    >
  <option  value="">- Select -</option>
  <option  value="1">1</option>
  <option  value="2">2</option>
  <option  value="3">3</option>
  <option  value="4">4</option>
  <option  value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
</div>

</div>




<div id="c103" class="form-group c103"  style="display: none" data-cid="c103">
  <label class="control-label" for="c103">Third dropdown</label>

<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon left"><i class="fa fa-stop-circle"></i> </span>
<select class="form-control" name="c103"   
    >
  <option  value="">- Select -</option>
  <option  value="1">1</option>
  <option  value="2">2</option>
  <option  value="3">3</option>
  <option  value="4">4</option>
  <option  value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using the unique ids for divs? Id has to be unique per page

Comment: Unique for every dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your fourth dropdown an id and register a change event the same way that you did with the #c86.
Assuming this is the 4th DropDown:

```
<div id="c104" class="form-group c104"  style="display: none" data-cid="c103">
  <label class="control-label" for="c103">Forth dropdown</label>

  <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon left"><i class="fa fa-stop-circle"></i> </span>
  <select class="form-control" name="c104" id="c104_dd"    >
    <option  value="">- Select -</option>
    <option  value="1">1</option>
    <option  value="2">2</option>
    <option  value="3">3</option>
    <option  value="4">4</option>
    <option  value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
  </div>

</div>
```

Give an id to the 3rd:

```
<select class="form-control" name="c103"   id="c103_dd"    >
  <option  value="">- Select -</option>
  <option  value="1">1</option>
  <option  value="2">2</option>
  <option  value="3">3</option>
  <option  value="4">4</option>
  <option  value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

and create a change event handler

```
$("#c103_dd").change(function()
{
    var selectedValue=$(this).val().toLowerCase();
  if(selectedValue == 1)
  {
    $("#c104").show();
  }
})
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1dhtu96g/8/)

Comment: Thanks it works fine! Just one question how can i do it after it appears dropdown 4 then when i choose -Select- on main choice to disappear everything? Now it keeps showing dropdown 4

Comment: Forget it i found it just add more cases at     case "-": 
    $("#c92").hide();   
    $("#c97").hide();
    $("#c103").hide();
    $("#c113").hide();
    $("#c118").hide();
    $("#c128").hide();
    $("#c133").hide();
    $("#c138").hide();
    $("#c143").hide();